# THREE.js - get cartesian plane of a SphereGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im building a tile engine which wraps a SphereGeometry and im struggling with getting the 2D plane of the geometry.
I need that because further im looking to get the visible area only in order to increase network efficiency.

Any ideea is welcomed.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs more details to fully understand what you're trying to achieve.

- Maybe you could look at the sphere's UVs. They're always mapped in 2D space in the `[0, 1]` range.
- Or you could use the `Spherical` class, which could take an `x, y, z` value, and it'll return `phi, theta, radius` values. You could use the `phi, theta` as latitude & longitude. [See here for documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Spherical.setFromCartesianCoords)